# Compare Two meta_values in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I feel like im extremely close on this one but the query keeps on showing up empty. Basically, Im trying to query the custom values between two dates. if the start date is less than the current date AND the end date is greater than or equal to the current date

```
        $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'exhibition_type', 
        'term' => 'faculty',
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
        'meta_key' => 'start_date_of_event',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'start_date_of_event',
                    'value' => $current,
                    'compare' => '<'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'end_event_date',
                    'value' => $current,
                    'compare' => '>='
                )
            ),
        'order_by' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' =>  $paged
    );
```

keeps on turning up 0 results :'( I'm stuck at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its possible. I entered my data in wrong :D

Here is the working code:

```
   $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'exhibition_type', 
    'term' => 'faculty',
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date_of_event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'start_date_of_event',
                'value' => $current,
                'compare' => '<'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end_date_of_event',
                'value' => $current,
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        ),
    'order_by' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' =>  $paged
);
```

This code uses two meta_values (start_date_of_event & end_date_of_event) and compares that to the current date which is ( $current = date('Ymd'); ). Hope this helps others. :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you I think this is your answer,

```
if(strtotime($args['meta_query'][0]['key']) > strtotime($args['meta_query'][1]['key'])){
     //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Im not trying to compare two queries. Im trying to create 1 query from the two custom values of start_date_of_event and end_date_of_event to out put the posts between the start date and end date.